# Vector can find the element

Tags: c++

So I have this simple project where I use vector to locate the questions and answer and when I run this the first part is okay it show the first element [0] in questions and if its correct then as shown in my while loop (at main) the numquestion should +1 and then the question which element is [1] will pop upans it actually works too. BUT the problem is when I type the correct answer at question [1] it wont work (Nile River is the correct answer) so it just while looping every time what did I do wrong?

```
vector <string> Questions = {
            "Where is the Great Barrier Reef located?",
            "What is the world’s longest river called?",
            "Which city hosted the Summer Olympics in 2012",
            "In Greek Mythology, who is the Queen of the Underworld and wife of Hades?",
            "Which house was Harry Potter almost sorted into?",
            "Which country gifted the Statue of Liberty to the US?"
        };
        vector <string> Answers = {
            "Australia","Nile River","London",
            "Persophone","Slytherin","France"
        };
```

where in my main is

```
int main()
{
    string contin;
    int lives = 3;
    int firstquestion = 0;
    string answer;
    Myname epoy;
    QandA epoy1;
    epoy.setname_address_age("JPR", "1045",22);
    while (lives > 0){
        epoy1.givequestion(firstquestion);
        cout<<"Your Answer: "<<endl;
        cin>>answer;
        epoy1.correct(answer,firstquestion); // my code below
        firstquestion++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

correct function

```
void QandA::correct(std::string answer,int numquestion)
{
    string tempor; // for cin on do while loop 
    if (answer == Answers[numquestion])
    {
        cout<<"Correct"<<endl;
        givescore();
    }
    else
    {
        do
        {
            cout<<"Wrong Answer"<<endl;
            givequestion(numquestion);
            cout<<"Answer: "<<endl;
            cin>>tempor;
            answer = tempor;
        }while(answer != Answers[numquestion]);
        cout<<"correct"<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `cin>>answer` will only read one *word*, not a whole line. Use [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead.

Comment: Oh wow! I forgot about that thanks man i will now close my question.